# jQuery UI Datepicker not working with function variables

Tags: php, jquery

I have created a form that has a "Form" and "To" input fields to query information. I can manually type in the date and it works fine (yyyy-mm-dd). However, I wanted to use the jQuery UI for convenience.

The problem is the the jQuery UI calendar does not appear. I am using the datepicker and it works fine on other pages with id "datapicker". i just cannot get it work with from using id "fromdate" and 'todate".

php code: index.php

```js
function showReviews(){
   //var fromdate = $( "#fromdate" ).val();
   //var todate= $( "#todate" ).val();
     var fromdate = $( "#fromdate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
     var todate= $( "#todate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
 
    var str= $( "#str" ).val();
  

  if (str == "" && fromdate =="" && todate=="")
    {
     document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
     return;
    } 

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
  else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    
 xmlhttp.open("GET","reviewdate.php?q="+str+"fromdate="+fromdate+"&todate="+todate,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only"></label>
    <p class="form-control-static">From Date:</p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fromDate" class="sr-only"></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fromdate" value="" onChange="showReviews()">
  </div>
                      
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only"></label>
    <p class="form-control-static">To Date:</p>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="toDate" class="sr-only"></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="todate" value="" onChange="showReviews()">
  </div>
</form>
```

I also have this code in my .js file

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
inline: true,
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

if I change the "id" in the form to datepicker, the jQuery UI shows the calendar. But I need to use the variables from the function showReviews().

Is there a way to add datepicker to the function variables "fromdate" and "todate"? Thanks for all your help! I have been searching all day long.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is

```
dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

Comment: Hi, I removed it from the variable. var fromdate = $( "#fromdate" ).datepicker().val();. It stills does not work. I was thinking the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: I'm an idiot.  The answer you are looking for is that #datepicker is not defined.  You need to use  $("#fromdate").----- and $("#todate")                    You are trying to call on datepicker on an element that doesn't exist.

Comment: The really strange thing. For some reason this php code: $set = (object)array_merge((array)$set,(array)$db_set);    Does allow the calendar dropdown to work. $set = new stdClass(); // stores general settings.